# How to call a method defined in others components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assuming we have two functional components App and Product. From the Product component you can easily call a method defined in the parent component (App) by simply passing the method as props (methodA={methodA}). Can someone please tell me how to call a method defined in the Cart component from the Product component?

```
//App.js
import React from "react";

import Cart from "./Cart";
import Order from "./Order";
import Product from "./Product";

const App = props => {

  const { order } = props;

  const methodA = props => {
    console.log(methodA);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Cart>
        {order.map((products, i) => {
          return (
            <Order key={i}>
              {products.map((items, i) => (
                <Product item={items} key={i} methodA={methodA} />
              ))}
            </Order>
          );
        })}
      </Cart>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App; 

//Product.js
import React from 'react';

const Product = props => {

    return <div className="delete" onClick={props.methodA}></div>;
};
export default Product;
```

Comment: You should take a look at React Context API, it will help you to solve the problem https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

That's why Redux is developed for easier state management. You should have Redux store and actions dispatched within this store. Once you have set up your redux store and actions, you can easily dispatch the same action from multiple components.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- Pass the products to the cart and let it render them (the best way in this case)
- Use some state management like context or redux (in this case, an context passed by the cart component would be perfect, then the product component consume and use it functions)